# Why is my Poliigon Metal Material way darker than its material preview?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm kind of a new to this whole render thing - I'm using some of Poliigons metal materials -Metal Stainless Steel Brushed 002 4K.

I can see the dents and brushed metal textures but the "base" color of the material is almost black? Its a stainless steel material so it should not be black right?

I have messed around with the lighting too to make sure that wasn't the issue - i don't think it is.

Why is it black? The preview material is much lighter.

[image]

Comment: are you in Render mode? In that case you need to make sure that your world is bright enough. Your material is metallic so it will reflect its environment, if it is dark, your texture will look dark, it may be the problem here

Comment: Im in render mode - It pretty strange -  I just increased the world strength as well. and it kind of helped but still check out the material preview on the right hand side it shows the metal as being all black? @moonboots i just uploaded a new image to better explain what im talkin about

Comment: could you please pack the images and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots file is uploaded

Comment: you need to paste the new web address that you get after upload here

Comment: derp - still learning https://pasteall.org/blend/f51210efa29845b8947015aed3d5da63 @moonboots

Comment: you need to pack the images into the blend file; which I believe you shouldn't do with paid textures from Poliigon, but if it's allowed, open the blend file, and in the File Menu -> External Data section select Pack all into .blend.  Save the file and then upload it.

Comment: Alright that made the file very large. Hope this works https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/10_F8nhdJ3kAgdvgNO4Nkl0Ifyjd3qT7n

Comment: hello, your link asks for authorization

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10_F8nhdJ3kAgdvgNO4Nkl0Ifyjd3qT7n?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey all thanks for the willingness to help me out on this - I figured it out... i just needed to download the metalness workflow from poliigon.